# Merge dataframes with duplicated rows in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, merge

I have three dataframes.

`df1 =`

| Ticker | Entry Price | Entry Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| HAVELLS | 1306.6 | 2015-01-02 |
| TRITUR | 115.43 | 2015-01-02 |

`df2 =`

| Ticker | Exit Price | Exit Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| BRITANNIA | 1200 | 2015-01-09 |
| TRITUR | 111.41 | 2015-01-09 |

`df3 =`

| Ticker | Entry Price | Entry Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| TRITUR | 112.01 | 2015-01-16 |

I want to combine these three dataframes to give a resulting dataframe of the form:

`df =`

| Ticker | Entry Price | Entry Date | Exit Price | Exit Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| HAVELLS | 1306.6 | 2015-01-02 | Price on date p | p |
| BRITANNIA | Price on date q | q | 1200 | 2015-02-09 |
| TRITUR | 115.43 | 2015-01-02 | 111.41 | 2015-01-09 |
| TRITUR | 112.01 | 2015-01-16 | Price on date p | p |

where `p`  and `q` are already defined as the ***last date of the current month***, and ***first date of the current month*** and so are the `prices on date p and q`.

I tried using groupby but that doesn't seem to work.
Please help.

Comment: How did `2015-01-16` become `2015-01-02`?

Comment: That was a typo, I have corrected it. Thanks a lot for pointing it out.

Comment: So, each dataframe has either an entry or exit data? and you want them in order?

Comment: Yes, and after the last entry I want to fill in the exit date with a predefined value.

Comment: Does each input dataframe only have a single row? What happens if there are different tickers?

Comment: I have edited my question to include such a scenario. All Tickers appearing in multiple dataframes are supposed to behave like "TRITUR", and the ones occurring in a single dataframe are supposed to behave like "HAVELLS"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can sort the dataframes depending on the entry/exit status, then [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) them after deduplicating per Ticker with [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
dfs = [df1, df2, df3]

entry = []
exit  = []
for x in dfs:
    if 'Entry Price' in x.columns:
        entry.append(x)
    else:
        exit.append(x)
         
out = (pd.concat([pd.concat(entry)
                    .sort_values(by='Entry Date',
                                 ignore_index=True)
                    .assign(n=lambda d: d.groupby('Ticker').cumcount())
                    .set_index(['Ticker', 'n']),
                  pd.concat(exit)
                    .sort_values(by='Exit Date',
                                 ignore_index=True)
                    .assign(n=lambda d: d.groupby('Ticker').cumcount())
                    .set_index(['Ticker', 'n'])],
                 axis=1)
         .reset_index('Ticker')
         .fillna({'Entry Price': 'Price on date q',
                  'Entry Date': 'q',
                  'Exit Price': 'Price on date p',
                  'Exit Date': 'p',
                 })

         .reset_index(drop=True)
      )
```

Output:

```
      Ticker      Entry Price  Entry Date       Exit Price   Exit Date
0    HAVELLS           1306.6  2015-01-02  Price on date p           p
1     TRITUR           115.43  2015-01-02           111.41  2015-01-09
2     TRITUR           112.01  2015-01-16  Price on date p           p
3  BRITANNIA  Price on date q           q           1200.0  2015-01-09
```